# Get the current time with GMT+2 in GoLang

Tags: date, datetime, go, time

I need to get the actual time in GMT+2 (Rome, Italy) in Go language.

I've used:
      time.Now()
but it returns the actual date in GMT+0.

I've seen that there's a In(loc *Location) function but I can't understand how to use it. And also, do you know if setting GMT+2, it also consider the DST option in automatic?

Could you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can user the function `FixedZone` or `LoadLocation` to get a `*Location`
And then use that `*Location` in `func In`

```
// get the location
location,_ := time.LoadLocation("Europe/Rome")

// this should give you time in location
t := time.Now().In(location)

fmt.Println(t)
```

Here is more of docs https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time

Answer (score 0):

According to @Vasif, this is the code which use `time.FixedZone` function

```
// the offset is second
var yourLocation = time.FixedZone("GMT+2", 2*60*60)
```

here is the doc
https://pkg.go.dev/time#FixedZone